# Jquery returns an error where it cannot find the property of an objects (Django)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, django

When I changed the import method I got an error on a live search.

This is the JQUERY code I'm using. The error I'm gettin is the blogpost['title'] is empty.
I've read that it might be due to the name blogpost being the overall container, so it's not actually a single blogpost but all the blogpost, but I don't know how to fix this. I think the most helpful would be someone taking a look at the rdata and the json error. Thanks!

```js
<script>
    var data = '{{qs_json}}'
    data = data.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
    data = data.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');
    console.log(data)
    rdata = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log(rdata)

    const input = document.getElementById('search_form')

    let filteredArr = []

    input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
        jsbox.innerHTML = ""
        filteredArr = rdata.filter(blogpost => blogpost['title'].toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()))
        if (filteredArr.length > 0) {
            filteredArr.map(blogpost => {
                jsbox.innerHTML += `
                <div class="col mt-5 ml-1">
                <a href="blog/${blogpost.slug}" style="text-decoration: none">
                    <div class= "card">
                        <div class='blogpost_image_container'>
                            <img src="${blogpost.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="blogpost image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">${blogpost.title} </h5>
                            <p class="card-text"> ${blogpost.subtitle} </p>
                            <span id="category_badge" class="badge rounded-pill bg-warning text-dark"> ${blogpost.category}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div > 
                </a> `
            })
        }
        else {
            jsbox.innerHTML = `<div class= "col mt-5 ml-1"> <h5 class="card-title"> No Matches Found! </h5></div >`
        }
    })

</script>
```

However the console logged Rdata shows something different:
[The Console logged rdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6Gam.png)

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TDHG.png)

This is my django view import:

```python
class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = "blog/blog.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.GET.get('category_filter'):
            cat_filter = self.request.GET.get('category_filter')
            all_blogposts = BlogPost.objects.filter(
                category=cat_filter)
            print(all_blogposts)
        else:
            all_blogposts = BlogPost.objects.all()

        data = serializers.serialize("json", all_blogposts)
        context["qs_json"] = data
        context["blogposts"] = all_blogposts
        context["categories"] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

And this is the forloop in the django template, not sure if it's useful.

```html
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 g-4" id="jsbox">
    {% for blogpost in blogposts %}
    <div class="col mt-5 ml-1">
        <div class="card">
            <a href="{% url 'blogpost' blogpost.slug %}">
                <div class='blogpost_image_container'>
                    <img src="{{ blogpost.image }}" class="card-img-top" alt="blogpost image">
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ blogpost.title }} </h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> {{ blogpost.subtitle}} </p>
                    <span id="category_badge" class="badge rounded-pill bg-warning text-dark">
                        {{ blogpost.category }}</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi, why you need to generated entire html again ? You can simply show/hide div depending on user input.

Comment: @Swati I think this is because of loading the django as a for-loop?

Comment: I think more easy way would be like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65650295/10606400)

Comment: @Swati thanks, much easier solution indeed!